# Kingston SSD is not recognized by BIOS after formatting

Tags: ssd, bios, troubleshooting

I have a Kingston SSD 120 GB 300V. It was working, but after I formatted it, even my BIOS fails to recognize it. What may be the cause? Is there any fix?

I have no other drivers, making it impossible to boot in any OS, and no other computers at my disposal.

It's in Dell Inspiron 3421 notebook. I guess you can find out the motherboard and other specs from the model, since it's all from the notebook bundle, except the SSD.

The SSD was formatted using Windows, on the OS setup boot (where you select which volume will be used for the new Windows installation).

It is connected using the notebook board, which recognizes every other HD, but this one. This SSD is not recognized in any other device I've tried (one other PC, and a USB hard drive enclosure)

I don't know about the RAID BIOS.

Comment: So it is not working now anywhere? It is very unlikly that formatting would cause it to not show up in the Deeper sections of the hardware visuals, like in device managers ?  Or in some desktop PCs bios/uefi (wherin a laptop bios might be more limited) .  From what you just said it sounds like it had a controller fail.   You could attempt a "Secure Erase" which is done more hardware based in the SSD, and see if that reset anything? (cant do that if it cant see it)  Modern PC motherbords can have a secure erase function in the UEFI.  Other than a fail (whats left) cables and power cabling.

Answer (score 1):

Formatting a drive would not cause a computer's BIOS not to see it.  The BIOS looks at the hardware, not the filesystem.  If the BIOS is not recognizing the drive, the drive may be faulty.  If you have a SATA to USB adapter (they are cheap if you dont) try connecting it to your computer that way and see if it works.  Also, you could test the drive in another computer to see if it is recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see if the drive is detected by smartctl. [GSmartControl](https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/) is a nice little Windows graphical utility for testing drives.

Comment: How could this possibly  work if BIOS doesnt see the drive?